# imacros running .iim without stopping

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have an issue with my imacros script: When I run AMF-Master.iim script.

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Followers.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Likes.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Post-Like.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Post-Share.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/G-Circles.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/MS-Friends.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/PT-Followers.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/PT-Likes.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/PT-Repins.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/TW-Favorites.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/TW-Followers.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/TW-Retweets.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/YT-Likes.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/YT-Subscribe.js
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/Daily-Bonus.js
```

First it starts running line3, URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Followers.js. And when it finishes running that, it stops right there. It does not run the fourth line which is URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Likes.js and the other lines as well. And all my .js file are located in the same folder on ADDMEFAST file. So what is the problem in here?

Answer (score 1):

‘iMacros’ for Firefox can run only one command like `URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=…` and it must be at the end of  a macro. (The reason is that this command ends up with an error.) So, if you want proceed with the following scripts, you may add the line which includes the command for the next script to play, i.e. for ‘FB-Followers.js’ it will be:

```
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Likes.js");
```

for 'FB-Likes.js':

```
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Post-Like.js");
```

etc.

Also you can try to write one control script (not macro) like so:

```
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Followers.js");
// time to finish the script (choose yourselves)
iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=3");
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Likes.js");
iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=3");
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Post-Like.js");
// ...
```

However more likely I would recommend the first suggestion, because the second one may have unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I did that, but I got a -910 syntax error. Here is my code.

here is the error:
can not parse macro line: iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=ADDMEFAST/FB-Post-Like.js"); (Error code: -910)

Comment: The code you mentioned must be in a script with 'js' extension, but not in a macro with 'iim' extension. So, make necessary changes in your file name.